# How to pass list of values dynamically to Ansible URI module

Tags: ansible

I have one `Jfrog` API URL using that I can all exiting/Created repos. I need to get those reposes and pass it to some other task to add one Group.

I need to get the naming replos like `dev-user1`, `dev-user1` among diffrent users and pass that in

`"repositories": ["dev-user1","dev-user2", "dev-user2"]` like that automatically pass then only I can create it as one group. May I know how can I do that.

```
 hosts: all
  gather_facts: yes
  tasks:
   - name: Create a repo
     uri:
       url: https://raju.jfrog.io/raju/api/repositories/ansiraj-testing12349
       method: POST
       user: admin
       password: xxxxx
       body: >
           {
            "rclass": "virtual",
            "packageType": "maven",
            "repositories": ["{{ item }}"],
            "handleSnapshots": false
           }
       force_basic_auth: yes
       status_code: 200
       body_format: json
     with_items: "{{ servernames.strip().replace(' ', '').replace(',', '\n').split('\n') }}"
```

ansible-playbook var-virtual.yml  --extra-var "servernames=ansiraju,ansiraj-testing"servernames

It is getting overwriting.

Even I have tried to pass like [this](https://ttl255.com/ansible-appending-to-lists-and-dictionaries/).
I am confusing how to pass values in URI module repositories.
can anyone help me on this